# Two or more embedded message system into jboss 4.x

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jms, hornetq, jbossmq

Im trying to migrate from default JbossMQ for Jboss 4.0.5 GA to a embebed HornetQ 2.2.14. I'm wondering if anyone know if is it possible to run the server with more than one message systems embedded??

Thanks in advance!